# Classes Parametrizadas com JUnit 4

Tags: java, testes, junit

Estou com um exercício pra resolver envolvendo classes parametrizadas em Java e estou um pouco confusa.

O exercício é o seguinte:

> Programar uma classe parametrizada para
>   testar o método areaQuadrado com os seguintes
>   valores de entrada e saída:
>
> ```
> {b:0, a:0, saída:0},
> {b:1, a:1, saída:1},
> {b:2, a:0, saída:0},
> {b:0, a:2, saída:0}
> ```

A classe que tem o método correspondente ao do exercício é essa:

```
package aula;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Operacao {
    /* retorna a área de um quadrado */
    public double areaRetangulo(double b, double a) throws Exception {
        if (b < 0 || a < 0) {
            throw new Exception("Valor negativo");
        }
        return b * a;
    }

    /*
     * retorna true se o objeto é um subtipo de Number
     */
    public boolean isNumber(Object obj) throws Exception {
        return obj instanceof java.lang.Number;
    }

    public int timer(int cont) throws InterruptedException {
        /* sleep por cont segundos */
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(cont);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Para poder testar Operacao, criei a seguinte classe utilizando o JUnit4:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import aula.Operacao;

import org.junit.Test;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class OurTest {

//  @Test
//  public void test() {
//      fail("Not yet implemented");
//  }

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double saida;
    private Operacao op;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        op = new Operacao();
    }

    public OurTest(double a, double b, double saida) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.saida = saida;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection parametros() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {0, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 1},
            {2, 0, 0},
            {0, 2, 0} });

        }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Testando: " +saida);
        assertEquals(b,a, op.areaRetangulo(b, a));
    }

    }
```

Porém, os resultados me deixaram meio confusa, foram os seguintes: os dois primeiros ficaram verdes e os dois últimos testes, azuis. Eu preciso torna-los todos verdes, alguém pode me explicar como funciona certinho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você cometeu uma certa confusão no método `assertEquals`.

Esse método recebe os parâmetros nessa ordem:

```
assertEquals(valorEsperado, valorAtualQueFoiRetornado)
```

Porém, no caso de valores do tipo `double`, o `assertEquals` apenas com esses dois parâmetros é considerado obsoleto. Para valores `double` além desses dois valores é necessário também passar um delta, dessa forma:

```
assertEquals(valorEsperado, valorAtualQueFoiRetornado, delta)
```

Esse delta é a precisão das casas decimais. No seu caso, sua chamada deveria ser assim:

```
assertEquals(saida, op.areaRetangulo(b, a), 0.0001);
```

Ou seja:

1. Valor esperado: saida
2. Valor sendo testado: op.areaRetangulo(b, a)
3. Precisão: 0.0001 - significa que os números serão verificados levando em consideração apenas 4 casas decimais. Se houver uma diferença na quinta casa decimal, ainda assim os números serão considerados iguais.

Você vai colocar o delta de acordo com a sua necessidade. Se você quiser 2 casas decimais, por exemplo, o delta seria 0.01